# making a pointer that stores an element of a char array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, tree, linked-list

I've been struggling trying to figure out why I am getting the following warning:
**initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast**

The highlighted warnings are where I mentioned below.  The code I am currently using is just the beginning of creating tree of elements in a linked list fashion. This code seems to be working fine however I get docked points for warnings.

```
typedef struct Node {
        struct Node *leftChild;
        struct Node *rightChild;
        char data;
} Node;

Node *TreeCreate(int level, const char *data) {
    struct Node *ptr = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof (Node));
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        // malloc failed
        return 0;
    }
    ptr->data = data;   // WARNING
    ptr->leftChild = NULL;
    ptr->rightChild = NULL;
    return ptr;
}
// TEST CODE IN MAIN
char list[6] = {'A', 'B', 'C','\0'};

// Determines the element
const char *tree = list[0]; // WARNING
ptr = TreeCreate(1, tree);
if (ptr != NULL) {
    sprintf(string, "TreeData: %c\n", ptr->data);
    OledDrawString(string);
    OledUpdate();
}
```

Comment: First [Don't cast the result of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1983495). Then, please post the declaration of `string`.

Comment: typedef'ing structs is always a bad idea and should be avoided

Comment: in C, the returned value from malloc (and family) should not be cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fundamental mistake is that you are assigning a poitner to a `char` which is wrong

```
const char *tree = list[0]; // WARNING
```

this will not yield the result you expect.

The `*` in this case is not dereferencing the pointe, you are declaring a poitner and pointeing to a `char` with it, then when you try to access the pointer, your program tries to read at an invalid memory address causing undefined behavior.

Then you do the opposite thing in

```
ptr->data = data;
```

you should enable compiler warnings to avoid this mistakes.

To handle the data you apparently want to handle, first you need to redefine the struct like this

```
typedef struct Node {
    struct Node *leftChild;
    struct Node *rightChild;
    char *data;
    /*   ^ this should be a char pointer */
} Node;
```

then in the `TreeCreate()` function, copy the data by first allocating space and then using `memcpy()` like this

```
Node *TreeCreate(int level, const char *data) {
    size_t       length;
    struct Node *ptr;

    ptr = malloc(sizeof (Node));
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (data != NULL)
    {
        length    = strlen(data);
        ptr->data = malloc(1 + length);
        if (ptr->data != NULL)
            memcpy(ptr->data, data, 1 + length);
    }
    else
        ptr->data = NULL;        

    ptr->leftChild  = NULL;
    ptr->rightChild = NULL;

    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: Additionally, it's the other way around at the top of the code. He's assigning a pointer to a char (in the line `ptr->data = data;   // WARNING` since ptr->data is a char.

Comment: @russianfool yes, I think the OP is mixing `char` poitners with `char`'s

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand.  The following fixed my warnings.  Thanks for the fast response!

```
const char *tree = &list[0];
ptr->data = *data;
```

Comment: Yea, not sure why our professor made us use a pointer input for Node *TreeCreate however maybe it holds more relevance down the line, I've only just started messing with this assignment.

Answer (score 0):

```
the following, a complete program, 
that cleanly compiles
and has the warnings fixed
and eliminates the clutter and unnecessary typedef statements.

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


struct Node 
{
        struct Node *leftChild;
        struct Node *rightChild;
        char data;
};

struct Node *TreeCreate(int level, const char *data) 
{
    struct Node *ptr = malloc(sizeof (struct Node));
    if (ptr == NULL) 
    {
        // malloc failed
        return NULL ;
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    ptr->data = *data;   // WARNING
    ptr->leftChild = NULL;
    ptr->rightChild = NULL;
    return ptr;
}

int main()
{
    struct Node *ptr = NULL;
    char  string[120] = {'\0'};

    // TEST CODE IN MAIN
    char list[6] = {'A', 'B', 'C','\0'};

    // Determines the element
    const char *tree = &list[0]; // WARNING

    ptr = TreeCreate(1, tree);

    if (ptr != NULL) 
    {
        sprintf(string, "TreeData: %c\n", ptr->data);
        //OledDrawString(string);
        //OledUpdate();
    }
    return 0;
}
```